# Body acne (extreme condition)

Tags: dermatology, acne, coloration-discoloration

After swelling goes away dark spots take place of them. my complete back is covered with dark spots . Urgent help required.

Comment: Welcome to health SE:-), any question with the words, 'severe', 'serious', 'extreme' and so on, requires medical attention.

Comment: Well if you can suggest any home remedies to lower the effects

Comment: Okay, I'll add some home remedies to my answer.

Comment: Welcome :-). Severe acne deserve the attention of a dermatologist. I hope you will get the help you need from your doctor.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, the problem is not acne by itself but dark spots or **postinflammatory hyperpigmentation** after acne has gone.

Here is one medical article ([Emedicine](http://emedicine.medscape.com/article/1069191-treatment?pa=US2Uc2r3cp5rcAcP4WxCGkDZ1TqRFaU8O3P3jzYCcKuMqqfkHdSHGjqpSyujH612LCEJNCrbkqLWYvqLrhntWA%3D%3D)) that describes the treatment. The treating substances include hydroquinone, tretinoin cream, corticosteroids, glycolic acid (GA), and azelaic acid. I don't think you should try these treatments on your own; ask a dermatologist about it.

I personally do not believe that home remedies would help, because dermatologists and studies do not really mention them.